What can cause a negative R-Squared (between) with Fixed Effects estimation
I'm analyzing the S&P500 companies for my master thesis about employee happiness and entrepreneurial orientation. I have a panel dataset (2016-2020) with 208 complete entries. My problem is that when I perform the FE estimation with entity fixed effects, my R-squared (between) is negative. Can someone explain how this is possible, what it means and how to solve it? The hyperlink is to the database I use. Underneath is an image of the python code I use.
Big big thanks in advance!!<3
Database


What is $R^2$ (between)?

For model 6 this are the R-squared values:
R-squared: 0.0758
R-squared (between): -0.1173
R-squared (Within): 0.0758
R-squared (OVerall): -0.0532

What I actually meant was: what is $R^2$ (between) as a formula, or at least as a conceptually meaningful statistic?

R-squared (between) is the explained variance by the model between the different entities (companies). Is combination of included variables able to predict the average values of the for the dependent variable accurately, or is the mean value a better representation

Is there any kind of adjustment for the parameter count the way the usual adjusted $R^2$ has?

I have 208 entities, so 207 fixed effects and all variables are predictors. I must admit I do not 100% understand you question. Excuse me for that

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
